# Office 365 Mailbox of unlicensed user

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, data-recovery, mailbox, shared-mailbox

I'm trying to find any softdeleted mailbox that may be in the *recycle bin*, due to the licence removal (office or Exchange).

Initialy I used `Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox` but the results where *null*

After this disappointing result I did `Get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers` to check if I was really connected,and I got 2 results, deleted 2 other users with mailboxs, now I have 1 result.

Now I have 3 questions:

 the initial one: *how do I find a mailbox of an user that has lost his licence?*, 

and a new one: *why do I have 1 result when I should have at least 2?*,

and a bonus: *if they where shared mailbox would it be any different?* 

BR

Vasco

Answer (score 2):

Try `get-mailbox -InactiveMailboxOnly`. Unlicensed mailboxes are not SoftDeletedMailboxes. That only occurs after the user is deleted or the mailbox is deleted.

Shared mailboxes don’t require a license, so it doesn’t apply here.

I’m not sure I understand your second question. If you delete a user from Office 365, the associated mailbox will change to SoftDeleted status and the user will show up in the recycle bin. Try `get-msoluser -all -ReturnDeletedUsers` instead.

Answer (score -2):

mailboxes whose license was removed become immediately unavailable but are not soft-deleted. Those mailboxes are not visible from the Exchange Admin console, nor set as inactive, unless you set retention/litigation. You do this by running

```
Get-MsolUser -UnlicensedUsersOnly | Where-Object MSExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq 2147483648
```

Comment: This needs an explanation. Don't just drop cryptic code here without explaining what it is supposed to do and how it would answer the question.

Comment: mailboxes whose license was removed become unavailable but are not soft-deleted. Those mailboxes are not set as inactive, unless you set retention/litigation.
The way I found was to list the recoverable mailboxes whose license was removed is using a particular MSExch attribute indicating that a mailbox exists 

`Get-MsolUser -UnlicensedUsersOnly | Where-Object MSExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq 2147483648`.
The values  can be found here: [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_exchon-mso_o365b/recipient-type-values/7c2620e5-9870-48ba-b5c2-7772c739c651)